# How to make the fields in the table(text) editable when clicked on edit button in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have put few hardcoded values into my table in a single column and other column with buttons EDIT & DELETE for each row. Whenever I click on edit option in the first row, the value present in 1st column and same row has to be editable . Similarly for delete, the entire row has to be deleted. Also there will be a ADD option, where the rows have to be populated with the edit and delete buttons

CODE

```html
<div id="resultset" style="display:none">

  <div class="table-responsive" align="centre" style="width:300px;margin-left: 10%;" readonly="readonly">
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" readonly="readonly">

      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td>Full Review </td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <button type="button" id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button type="button" id="clearBtn" class="btn btn-info" onclick='onReset();'>Delete</button>


            </div>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>GHS Review</td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <button type="button" id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-info" onclick='onEdit();'>Edit</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button type="button" id="clearBtn" class="btn btn-info" onclick='onReset();'>Delete</button>


            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Maintenance Review</td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <button type="button" id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-info" onclick='onEdit();'>Edit</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button type="button" id="clearBtn" class="btn btn-info" onclick='onReset();'>Delete</button>


            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Handoff</td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <br>
              <br>
              <button type="button" id="EditBtn" class="btn btn-info" onclick='onEdit();'>Edit</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button type="button" id="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-info" onclick='onReset();'>Delete</button>


            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? A [mcve] would be perfect. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please put the code you have done so far.

Comment: Done. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need input fields, so you have text field editable. You might want to take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text.

So if you want to have table that will later be editable on button my best chocie and easyest would be so for you to have   and upon clicking to remove the disable attribute.

Comment: I have put all the fields as input now, whats the next thing I should be doing